# Polymer iron-image dynamic sizing doesn't work on Safari

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to fit a grid of iron-images perfectly onto the screen by computing the correct width and height as a property and using this in the style attribute of an iron-image. This works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

```
<dom-module id="x-example">
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<template>
    <div>
        image sizes should be {{imgWidth}} x {{imgWidth}}px
    </div>
    <iron-image src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="width: {{imgWidth}}px; height:{{imgWidth}}px" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>
    <iron-image src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="width: {{imgWidth}}px; height:{{imgWidth}}px" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>  
    <iron-image src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="width: {{imgWidth}}px; height:{{imgWidth}}px" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    Polymer({
        is: 'x-example',
        properties: {
            imgWidth: {
                type: Number,
                value: function () {
                    return Math.round(window.innerWidth / 2); 
                }
            },
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work on Safari (desktop or mobile)? The images don't show up at all.

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hpta04h6/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style` is a native attribute, but you're not using [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding) (`attr$="value"`). You're actually setting a new property named `style` on `<iron-image>`, which has no effect on styling the element in Safari.

To fix, simply switch `style="..."` to `style$="..."`:

```
<iron-image style$="width: {{imgWidth}}px; height:{{imgWidth}}px" ...></iron-image>
<iron-image style$="width: {{imgWidth}}px; height:{{imgWidth}}px" ...></iron-image>  
<iron-image style$="width: {{imgWidth}}px; height:{{imgWidth}}px" ...></iron-image>
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gmXrwV?editors=1010)

<sup>Tested in Safari 10.0.3 and Safari Technology Preview 10.2 (Release 5)</sup>

Comment: Ugh, totally forgot about attribute binding. The fact that it was working in Chrome/FF (why is this?) made me think that I wasn't missing something fundamental. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RonanCremin No problem :)